# Agrupar valores por indice igual y sumar atributos en php

Tags: php, php7, lógica, php8

me encuentro con un problema , tengo un array asociativo en el cual tengo ciudades y comparendos pueden haber ciudades repetidas entonces la idea es agrupar las ciudades y sumar sus comparendos para que no queden ciudades con comparendos individuales revueltos sino  agruparlas y sumar dicho comparendo por ciudad no me funciona, logre sacarlo con 3 arreglos los valores corectos pero al insertar mas datos en el arreglo asociativo sucede que se distorciona y reparte los comparendos para las demas ciudades , pero al final sumaban el total de comparendos que tengo solo que los reparte erradamente en todas las ciudades que tengo, tengo este codigo :

```
introducir el código aquí

<?php
//tenemos la data en un array asociativo
$datos=[
[
 "ciudad"=>"medellin",           
 "comparendos"=>1,
],
[
    "ciudad"=>"cali",
    "comparendos"=>5,    
   ],
   [
    "ciudad"=>"medellin", 
    "comparendos"=>2,
   ],
  

];





//contamos los elementos del arreglo principal
$total_array_principal= count($datos);
/*creamos un array para ir almacenando los datos finales agrupados por 
ciudades y sumando los comparendos de la misma ciudad*/
$datos_finales=[];



for($i=0;$i<$total_array_principal;$i++){
    $ciudad=$datos[$i]['ciudad'];
    $comparendos=$datos[$i]['comparendos'];
    /*aca validamos la ciudad no esta en la busqueda en los datos finales la aññadimos 
    y si ya esta eliminamos el indice le sacamos el valor e comparendos
    lo sumamos en este y elimianmos el otro y metemos este en array push
    */
    $found_key = array_search($ciudad, array_column($datos_finales, 'ciudad'));
    //esa funcion me retorna el indice del array entonces si no lo encuentra retorna vacio y si si numerico
        if(is_numeric($found_key)){
           $comparendo=$datos_finales[$found_key]['comparendos']+$comparendos;
            //$comparendos=$comparendo +$comparendos;
            //$ciudad=$datos_finales[$found_key]['ciudad'];
          
            $insertar=[
                'ciudad'=>$ciudad,
                'comparendos'=>$comparendo
            ];
            array_push($datos_finales,$insertar);
            unset($datos_finales[$found_key]);
     
           }else{
            $insertar=[
                'ciudad'=>$ciudad,
                'comparendos'=>$comparendos
            ];
            array_push($datos_finales,$insertar); 
           }
    }


    
 foreach($datos_finales as $data){

    echo "ciudad ".$data['ciudad']." comparendo ".$data['comparendos'];
    echo "<br>";
 }







    introducir el código aquí
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sencilla sería la de agrupar por ciudades en un nuevo array cuya clave principal sea, precisamente, el nombre de la ciudad. Así cada vez que te refieras a una ciudad en concreto, irás al mismo índice del nuevo array.

Así, en tu ejemplo, el primer paso barriendo tu array nos daría este como resultado:

```
$["medellin"]["ciudad"]="medellin"
$["medellin"]["comparendos"]=1
```

pero cuando encontrásemos otra vez "medellin", y sumásemos los comparendos:

```
$["medellin"]["ciudad"]="medellin"
$["medellin"]["comparendos"]=3
```

y al final el nuevo array tendrá dos claves principales "medellin" y "cali", y cada uno, los campos que tú ya tenías, "ciudad" y "comparendos".

```
$datos=[
[
 "ciudad"=>"medellin",           
 "comparendos"=>1,
],
[
    "ciudad"=>"cali",
    "comparendos"=>5,    
   ],
   [
    "ciudad"=>"medellin", 
    "comparendos"=>2,
   ],
];

$nuevo=array();  //array destino

foreach($datos as $i=>$v) //$v['ciudad'] será el índice principal 
                          //que vamos a usar en el nuevo array
{
   //asignamos el valor de "ciudad" al campo secundario "ciudad"
   $nuevo[$v["ciudad"]]["ciudad"]=$v["ciudad"];                                                          

   //la primera vez, inicializamos el campo de los comparendos
   //a un número válido para poder ir sumando sobre este.
   if(!isset($nuevo[$v["ciudad"]]["comparendos"])) 
      $nuevo[$v["ciudad"]]["comparendos"]=0; 

   //sumamos el valor del campo secundario con los que vayan saliendo
   $nuevo[$v["ciudad"]]["comparendos"]+=$v["comparendos"]; 

}


    var_dump($nuevo); //resultado

array(2) { 
["medellin"]=> array(2) { 
       ["ciudad"]=> string(8) "medellin" 
       ["comparendos"]=> int(3)
       } 
["cali"]=> array(2) { 
       ["ciudad"]=> string(4) "cali"
       ["comparendos"]=> int(5)
       } 
    }
```

Por último, y si te es necesario, se podría reconvertir el nuevo array a uno no asociativo (con clave principal numérica) para que tuviera la estructura del tuyo inicial.

```
    $arrayFinal=array();
    $n=0;
    foreach($nuevo as $i=>$v)
    {
            $arrayFinal[$n]["ciudad"]=$v["ciudad"];
            $arrayFinal[$n]["comparendos"]=$v["comparendos"];
            $n++;
    }
    
    var_dump($arrayFinal);

array(2) { 
   ["ciudad"]=> string(8) "medellin"
   ["comparendos"]=> int(3) 
}

[1]=> array(2) {
   ["ciudad"]=> string(4) "cali"
   ["comparendos"]=> int(5) } 
}
```

Comment: PHP 7 o superior, te puedes "ahorrar" el `if - isset / else` con [operador de fusión de null](https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op): `$nuevo[$v["ciudad"]]["comparendos"] = ($nuevo[$v["ciudad"]]["comparendos"] ?? 0) + $v["comparendos"];` Es un azucar sintáctico, pero hace el código más legible.